# Error when trying to build Linux documentation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, documentation

I have Linux git repository cloned, latest version of sphinx, GNU make, python, and all dependencies handled, running on MacOS (making the documentation to modify Linux on a VM), I am getting the following error when I attempt to make the Linux documentation:

```
% make xmldocs
make[1]: *** Documentation/Kbuild: Is a directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:1816: xmldocs] Error 2
```

I get the same error even when running in a Python venv with sphinx installed according to `./scripts/sphinx-pre-install`.

I run `make` at top-level of linux directory that I cloned. Could anyone please tell me what's going wrong?

I've also found that I could potentially do this by `scripts/kernel-doc` but I am unsure how to specify all the relevant files as its argument.